# How to do a jquery http post request to an API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

I have some problems to understand how I have to do to save a new user  with myKeyVals  username : "bruno", password : "login" to the API.
I have tried to use the code bellow, and It is displaying an alert"Save Compplete", but where have I saved  username : "bruno", password : "login"?
How can I do a jquery post request to an API, with url: `http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/?username=ith&password=ithith` (I can open the file url local)?
Can somebody gice me a hint?

```
var myKeyVals = { username : "bruno", password : "login"}

var saveData = $.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/?username=ith&password=ithith",
    data: myKeyVals.toString(),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

Comment: You are already doing post request to this url. http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/ now which webservice it calls and what is the output that you can check by parsing resultData argument of success call back function

Comment: @mitpatoliya Hi, OK, I understand... But how do I do to see that the data is posted? How should  do a callback?

Answer (score 0):

---

You should not convert the object `myKeyVals` to string.

So your code should look like:

```
var myKeyVals = {
    username : 'bruno',
    password : 'login'
};

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/?username=ith&password=ithith',
    data: myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json'
});


jqxhr.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('Succeed:', data);
});

jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Failed:', errorThrown);
});
```

---

**Update (server side):**

From the server side you should answer with valid JSON string.
As you said in comments you use PHP on the server so the example could look like:

```
<?php
$response = array("success" => true,);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Hi, nice code... But I get this warnings and errors: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in <b>/var/www/html/api/v11/Json.php(34) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/var/www/html/api/v11/Json.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/var/www/html/api/v11/index.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />

Comment: So maybe you should use some [`json_decode`](http://ua2.php.net/json_decode) on your PHP side before working with the data from request?

Comment: IM getting this error when I run your script Failed:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: A response from the server should be a valid JSON string. For example: `'{"success: "1"}'`. You can use PHP [`json_decode`](http://ua1.php.net/json_decode) to serialize a PHP associative array to JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I could be wrong but it seems that you're passing username and password twice: one in data and another in the url via GET "?username=ith&password=ithith" ?
Try this:

```
var myKeyVals = { username : "bruno", password : "login"};

var saveData = $.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/",
    data: myKeyVals,
    success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

Comment: If it alerted "something went wrong" means that the server returned an error.